# set factor levels in specific order

Tags: r, dplyr

How to set levels in specific order?
The desired order of levels are - `"CA", "IN", "FL" "NY"`

```
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble(states = c("FL", "NY", "CA", "IN")) %>%
  mutate(states_fct = factor(states))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `levels =` argument.

```r
tbl <- tibble(states = c("FL", "NY", "CA", "IN")) %>%
  mutate(states_fct = factor(states, levels = c("CA", "IN", "FL", "NY"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ordered` to express that you want an ordered factor:

```
states = ordered(c("FL", "NY", "CA", "IN"), levels = c("CA", "IN", "FL", "NY"))
str(states)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fct_relevel` from `forcats` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
tbl <- tibble(states = c("FL", "NY", "CA", "IN")) %>%
    mutate(states_fct = factor(states)) %>% 
    mutate(states_fct = fct_relevel(states_fct, c("CA", "IN", "FL", "NY")))

levels(tbl$states_fct)
```

Output:

```
  states states_fct
  <chr>  <fct>     
1 FL     FL        
2 NY     NY        
3 CA     CA        
4 IN     IN        

> levels(tbl$states_fct)
[1] "CA" "IN" "FL" "NY"
```